# Looping, iteration and returns - Increasing understanding

Tags: javascript

So I have a simple for `loop` that loops over an array and uses some conditional statements to log a string.

```
myArray = [12, 17, 19]

function testLoop () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(i);

    if (myArray[i] == 12) {
      console.log('is 12')
    } else if (myArray[i] == 17) {
      console.log('is 17')
    } else {
      console.log('Default')
    }
 }
};

testLoop();



myArray = [12, 17, 19]

    function testLoop () {
      for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        console.log(i);

        if (myArray[i] == 12) {
          return 'is 12'
        } else if (myArray[i] == 17) {
          return 'is 17'
        } else {
          return 'Default'
        }

     }
    };

    testLoop();
```

So my question is now this, we are using `return` within the function however are output is now `0`, and nothing else from the console. I understand that the return words end execution, I really don't understand why this is stopping iteration from occurring. A function ideally needs to also return something for it to be testable.

Please can someone clearly explain in detail why these conditionals will not run inside a loop and why we are not cycling over each item of `myArray` and returning a result.

Comment: `return` ends the function.

Comment: Which ends the loop as well

Comment: [The return statement ends function execution and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return)

Comment: A generator function can `yield` values to the outside and can continue execution then, regular functions `return` once and don't continue their execution.

Answer (score 0):

The way this is written:

```js
myArray = [12, 17, 19];

function testLoop () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(i);

    if (myArray[i] == 12) {
      return 'is 12'
    } else if (myArray[i] == 17) {
      return 'is 17'
    } else {
      return 'Default'
    }

 }
};

console.log(testLoop());
```

The return clause will be hit at first iteration and the loop will end because the function execution itself end immediately when a return is encountered.

The console logs 0 because it's the first statement of your loop `console.log(i)`.

I've added a console.log of the test loop return to show it returns 'is 12' at first iteration.

I think what you were expecting was something like [yield](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Op%C3%A9rateurs/yield) which allows returning values in a loop to be converted in an iterator

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you shouldn't use same function name for two declarations, and secondly all you need to do is console.log the returned value so that it can print what it has returned.
See that fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/v63wgpf4/

```
myArray = [12, 17, 19]

function testLoop () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(i);

    if (myArray[i] == 12) {
      return 'is 12'
    } else if (myArray[i] == 17) {
      return 'is 17'
    } else {
      return 'Default'
    }

 }
}

console.log(testLoop());
```

Answer (score 0):

As Nina said return ends the function, you should yeld keyword :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield

```js
function* foo () { 
 yield 12;
 yield 17;
 yield 19;
}
const iterator = foo();
var index = 0;
while (index++ < 3)
  console.log (iterator.next().value);
```